# How to text data download through libcurl with display QProgressBar?

Tags: c++, c, qt

I have Successfully done to download text data through curl programming and having display with Qt Ui progress bar .I hope this code will help for QT developer.Only speed calculate is something wrong .here is my resolve code.

Note:

1)For &progressdownload::WriteCallback should be  static function.

2)QProgresbar obj should be static declared.

```
     pbar =new  QProgressBar(this);
     pbar->setGeometry(10,80,305,30);
     pbar->setTextVisible(true);
```

/*************Download text file code here*******************/

```
 int progressdownload::downloadfile()
  {

    CURLcode res;
    QString filename="pi.txt";
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(filename.toStdString().c_str(), "wb");
    std::string readBuffer;
    curl_download = curl_easy_init();

    if (curl_download)
    {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_download, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.gecif.net/articles/mathematiques/pi/pi_1_million.txt");
    //curl_easy_setopt(curl_download, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, NULL);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_download, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &progressdownload::WriteCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_download, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_download, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, FALSE);
    //progress_bar : the fonction for the progress bar

    curl_easy_setopt(curl_download, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, &progressdownload::progress_func);
    qDebug()<<" Start download"<<endl<<endl;

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl_download);
    std::cout<<readBuffer<<std::endl;
    if (res == CURLE_OK) {
        printf("File downloaded!\n\n");
    } else {
        printf("Transfer failed!");
    }
    double download_speed = 0;
    double timeval = 0;
    double downloadSize = 0;
    curl_easy_getinfo(curl_download, CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD, &downloadSize);
    curl_easy_getinfo(curl_download, CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME, &timeval);
    curl_easy_getinfo(curl_download, CURLINFO_SPEED_DOWNLOAD, &download_speed);
    printf("size: %f, time: %f, download speed: %f\n", downloadSize, timeval, download_speed);

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl_download);
    fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}

int progressdownload::progress_func(void* ptr, double TotalToDownload, double NowDownloaded,
                                double TotalToUpload, double NowUploaded)
{

    if(TotalToDownload <= 0.0)
    {
    return 0;
    }

    QTime downloadtimer;
    downloadtimer.start();
    int curtime =downloadtimer.elapsed();
    qDebug()<<"ctime"<<curtime;
    int speed1 =((int)NowDownloaded*1000.0)/downloadtimer.elapsed();

    QString unit;
    if(speed1 <1024)
    {
    unit="bytes/sec";
    }else if(speed1 < 1024*1024){
    speed1/=1024;
    unit ="kB/s";
    }else{
    speed1/=1024*1024;
    unit="MB/s";
    }
    qDebug()<<"speed1"<<speed1;
    line1->setText(QString::fromLatin1("%1 %2").arg(speed1,4,'f',1).arg(unit));
    line1->show();
    olddownload =NowDownloaded;
    oldtime = QTime().currentTime().second();

    // how wide you want the progress meter to be
    int totaldotz=40;
    double fractiondownloaded = NowDownloaded / TotalToDownload;
    // part of the progressmeter that's already "full"
    int dotz = round(fractiondownloaded * totaldotz);

    // create the "meter"
    int ii=0;
    printf("%3.0f%% [",fractiondownloaded*100);
    qDebug()<<"values are"<<fractiondownloaded*100;
    double myval =fractiondownloaded*100;

    //Progress set
    int progress = static_cast<int>(myval);
    qDebug()<<"y"<<progress;

    pbar->setValue(progress);
    pbar->show();

    //Console output meter
    for ( ; ii < dotz;ii++) {
    printf("=");

    }
    // remaining part (spaces)
    for ( ; ii < totaldotz;ii++) {
    printf(" ");
    }
    // and back to line begin - do not forget the fflush to avoid output buffering problems!
    printf("]\r");
    fflush(stdout);
    // if you don't return 0, the transfer will be aborted - see the documentation
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You did not say which version of libcurl you are using. Per the documentation: "*Strings passed to libcurl as 'char *' arguments, are copied by the library; thus the string storage associated to the pointer argument may be overwritten after curl_easy_setopt returns... Before version 7.17.0, strings were not copied. Instead the user was forced keep them available until libcurl no longer needed them.*" So your use of `url.toStdString().c_str()` for `CURLOPT_URL` may or may not work. Best to use a local variable instead: `std::string s = url.toStdString(); curl_easy_setopt(..., s.c_str()):`

Comment: Also, using `progressdownload::progress_bar` for `CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION` can only work if `progress_bar` is declared as `static`.

Comment: i am using curl version 4.0.0.@Remy Lebeau

Comment: According of your suggest i have done download successfully so thank you very much .and one thing my progress meter function does not working i have added my progress meter function code.what was my wrong please check it out.@ Remy Lebeau

Comment: is `progress_bar` static? You did not show the declaration of your `progressdownload` class. But more importantly, this is another case where you clearly didn't read the documentation: "*Returning a non-zero value from this callback will cause libcurl to abort the transfer and return CURLE_ABORTED_BY_CALLBACK.*" You need to use `return 0;` instead of `return NowDownloaded;`

Comment: After rectified the code i am able to display  progress meter on  console output but when i am ui->progreessbar->setvalue() doing in same func but segmentation fault  happening .@ Remy Lebeau

Comment: You still haven't answered my question. Is the progress function declared as `static` or not? It makes a difference. And where is `ui` declared and how is it being initialized? You keep showing more code snippets, but you haven't shown an actual [mcve]. And your progress function is not `return`ing a value when `TotalToDownload > 0`. And you are passing the `this` pointer to `CURLOPT_PROGRESSDATA` so it gets passed to the progress function, but you are not using that pointer (in the `ptr` parameter) inside the progress function at all.

Comment: Fast of all i have declared Qprogresbar static as your suggested After that it's working fine .So i would like to many many thanks to you for your kind  support and one last Question was how to calculate download speed per sec periodically?I have shared resolve edited code ,you can see. please give your feed back.